# The fastest way to convert from native to manage for unsigned short in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, .net, optimization, c++-cli

I have a function to convert from native to managed code for unsigned short in C++/CLI, but my method requires calling copying twice. Is there any other way to make this process faster ?

```
//input
unsigned short* m_rawDataPtr; 
//output
array<uns16>^ m_rawData;

...
int size = data.GeSize();
array<short>^ dataSigned = gcnew array<short>( size / 2);
m_rawData = gcnew array<unsigned short>((int)size / 2);

Marshal::Copy(IntPtr((void*)(m_rawDataPtr),dataSigned, 0, dataSigned->Length);
System::Buffer::BlockCopy(dataSigned, 0, m_rawData, 0, (Int32)(size));
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
//input
unsigned short* m_rawDataPtr; 
//output
array<unsigned short>^ m_rawData;

cli::pin_ptr<unsigned short> pinnedManaged = &m_rawData[0];
std::memcpy(pinnedManaged , m_rawDataPtr, arrayLength * sizeof(unsigned short));
```

Comment: Is the deallocated by GC if it's not using if pin_ptr and memcpy are used ?